# How can I kill off a gnome-terminal completely?

Tags: c++, linux, gnome-terminal

I noticed when I do the following, the gnome-terminal simply goes into "Zombie State"

```
char *cmd = "kill <pidofterminal>"
popen(cmd, "r");
```

Is there a way to completely kill off the program? I need it to release its PID.

Comment: How about specify kill command with -9, `"kill -9 <pidofterminal>"`?

Comment: somehow when i try to do a kill -9 <pid> in my program, the terminal simply goes into Zombie state...but when i do kill -9 in a terminal, it kills the gnome-terminal off totally, any idea why is that so?

Comment: are you `root or sudo` when you run your program?

Comment: To billz: no its not. will something like "chmod u+s /sbin/shutdown" solve the problem? i not sure where the kill executable is located.

Comment: `kill` command is in `/bin/kill`, you could run `which` or `whereis` to locate it

Answer (score 1):

You could specify `-9` in kill command

```
char *cmd = "kill -9 <pidofterminal>"
popen(cmd, "r");
```

Run program under sudo or root:

```
sudo ./program
```

It will kill all processes you can kill.

Comment: i tried chmod -v u+s /path/to/yourapp and chmod u+s /bin/kill but doesnt work

Comment: trying to give my app root permssion

Comment: chmod u+s will give permission to run but not the permission to kill :), you need root or sudo privilege

Comment: i noticed when i close my program(parent), the gnome-terminal will be completely killed off, is there a way to prevent the need to close off my program?

Comment: I am a bit confused by you, I guess you want start a detached gonme-terminal, specify `&` in the end of starting command